# How to add two variables in PHP without getting "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\game\test.php on line 28 0" error

Tags: php, variables, numeric

```
     $var1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['var1'])
     $var2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['var2']);
     $var3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['var3']);
     $var4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['var4']);



 $data = $var1*10+$var2*10+$var3*10+var4*10;
 echo $data;
```

I get

```
 "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\game\test.php on line 28"
```

error whenever I try to `echo $data`.

I only get the error whenever one of the input fields is left empty.

So can someone please **tell me a way** to fix this error using `php` code or the right way to add variables so I don't get the error?

Comment: set variable to 0 if empty

Comment: you should use Type Casting `$var1= (int)$var1; $var1= (float)$var1;` and check if $var1 is empty or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have forgot the semicolon after `$var`.

Second, within your `$data`, you forgot to make `var4` a variable, `$var4`.

**Your code:**

Lets say `$var1` to `$var4` are numbers.

```
<?php

    $var1 = 1;
    $var2 = 2;
    $var3 = 3;
    $var4 = 4;

    $data = $var1 * 10 + $var2 * 10 + $var3 * 10 + $var4 * 10;

    echo $data; // Outcome: 100.
?>
```

To check if your variables are **integers** or not, you can simply do something like this:

```
<?php

$post_var1 = (isset($_POST['var1'])) ? (int) $_POST['var1'] : 0; // PHP shorthand If/Else
$post_var2 = (isset($_POST['var2'])) ? (int) $_POST['var2'] : 0;
$post_var3 = (isset($_POST['var3'])) ? (int) $_POST['var3'] : 0;
$post_var4 = (isset($_POST['var4'])) ? (int) $_POST['var4'] : 0;

$var1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $post_var1);
$var2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $post_var2);
$var3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $post_var3);
$var4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $post_var4);

$data = $var1 * 10 + $var2 * 10 + $var3 * 10 + $var4 * 10;

echo $data; 
?>
```

**Documentation `Shorthand If/Else`**

- https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

Personally I would create a function for this, but that is up to you. Remember you should '**decorate**' your code which means you also need to be able to read your code after a week or so, in case you need to improve/debug it ;-). Just a small adding for you:

Try to use **documentation** like:

```
<?php

/**
 * Set up all variables to calculate with.
 * First of all there is a check on the $_POST data, it must be integer.
 * Second is to set the data.
 * @todo: Create function instead of handwriting
 */
$post_var1 = (isset($_POST['var1'])) ? (int) $_POST['var1'] : 0;
$post_var2 = (isset($_POST['var2'])) ? (int) $_POST['var2'] : 0;
$post_var3 = (isset($_POST['var3'])) ? (int) $_POST['var3'] : 0;
$post_var4 = (isset($_POST['var4'])) ? (int) $_POST['var4'] : 0;

/**
 * Do the mysqli statements,
 */
$var1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $post_var1);
$var2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $post_var2);
$var3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $post_var3);
$var4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $post_var4);

/**
 * $data calculation.
 */
$data = $var1 * 10 + $var2 * 10 + $var3 * 10 + $var4 * 10;

/**
 * $data result
 */
echo $data;
?>
```

**Documentation `docblocks`**

- http://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/docblocks.html

**Documentation `isset()`**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

**Documentation `integer`**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: I believe you are nitpicking on copy paste errors with the `;` and `$`

Comment: Sad to read this kind of feedback, it is not nitpicking. Because no code will work with these kind of 'nitpicking' errors.

Comment: You are not understanding. I believe OP made a mistake when writing the question. The real code has correct syntaxes.

Comment: Let us hope for that!

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need, Upvoted! And sorry for the confusion in my question part.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to check if your variables exist first.

```
if(isset($var1) && isset($var2) && isset($var3) && isset($var4)) {
    $data = $var1 * 10 + $var2 * 10 + $var3 * 10 + var4 * 10;
    echo $data;
}
```

This code will check if your variables are set first, meaning if your variables have a value and then will try to do the math otherwise it will skip this part of the code.

```
if($var1!=='' && $var2!=='' && $var3!=='' && $var4!=='') {
    $data = $var1 * 10 + $var2 * 10 + $var3 * 10 + var4 * 10;
    echo $data;
}
```

If your variables are set but are empty then you need to do the second control.

If there is a chance that your query will return a value different than a number then you can use the [is_numeric](http://is_numeric) function to ensure that your variables are all numbers.

```
if(is_numeric($var1) && is_numeric($var2) && is_numeric($var3) && is_numeric($var4)) {
    $data = $var1 * 10 + $var2 * 10 + $var3 * 10 + var4 * 10;
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: How can an integer variable be an empty string?

Comment: Based on what is described his variables can be empty strings. If it was a boolean return (1,0) it would have no problem to go through the math. So either it is returning an empty string or is not set at all. I will also edit my answer to check specific for numeric values as well.

Comment: No, your this condition is logically incorrect.  `if($var1!=='' && $var2!=='' && $var3!=='' && $var4!=='') `. The condition will also return true it is not an empty `STRING`

Comment: I tried your code and I still get the same error, when I leave the input empty, I want the input value to become 0 when the user leaves it empty(or when he clears the 0 in the input field as I have its value set to 0) 
So I want those variables to get added but if one of them is empty, the empty one should become number zero, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code as it checks either php variable is numeric or not

```
if(is_numeric($var1) && is_numeric($var2) && is_numeric($var3) && is_numeric($var4) && is_numeric($var5))
 {
   $data = $var1*10+$var2*10+$var3*10+var4*10;
   echo $data;
 }
else
  echo "Sorry! We have encountered non-numeric variables."
```

Comment: That only checks if it is int I guess and then echoes "Sorry! We have encountered non-numeric variables." if its not

But I want to get a numeric value as result even if one of the input fields was left empty, so how do I set empty input field submission to number zero?

Comment: Then @Andreas answer is best solution for you

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest is to do an if and replace the value if it's empty.

```
$vars[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['var1']);
$vars[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['var2']);
$vars[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['var3']);
$vars[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['var4']);

$data =0;
foreach($vars as &$var){
    if($var =="" || is_string($var)) $var =0;
    $data += $var*10;
}
echo $data;
```

Comment: Suppose if it has a non-empty `string` then?